# warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

i am getting this error when i run my flutter app.

3 warnings
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

I am using gradle 8.1 version. after configuring my project with firebase, i am getting this error. Is the problem causes for gradle version 8.1?
on the other hand, i can't use gradle version 7.5 because of my jdk version.

Answer (score 0):

edit your build.gradle.kts & replace :

> compileOptions {
> sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
> targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

with :

> compileOptions {
> sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
> targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17 }

or go to File-Project Structure- Modules- Properties & choose your version of Source Compatibility & Target compatibility  (mine is 17)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: but i'm using Gradle version 8.1, is there any problem with it??